# Get the name of a window using Windows API

Tags: python, winapi

I am new to python and I am trying to write a script that exits out of a loop when a certain window closes.  I am having problems getting the code to work properly it won't even enter the loop.  I think this is because I am not properly getting the window name.  I was wondering if there are any good tutorials on the Win32Gui extension that would help me to understand how it works.

Edit

Here is what I have, it is doing what it is suppose to do, but I am sure there is an easier way of doing it.

```
def answerCalls(local, network):
t = 0
count = 0
while t == 0:
    time.sleep(1)
    if win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) == "Incoming Call":
        time.sleep(10)   
        getApplicationPos("Incoming Call")
        clickOnElement(******.IncomingCall_AnswerButton())
        time.sleep(10)
        if win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) == "Video Call":
            count += 1
            writeFile("Answering Calls", count, local)
            uploadToServer(local, network)
```

Comment: It doesn't really differ terribly from how it would be done in any other language.

Comment: If you show your code we could help with it specifically.

Comment: What exactly are you trying that's not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example (Python 3) gets a list of the titles of all the windows:

```
import win32gui

def enum_window_titles():
    def callback(handle, data):
        titles.append(win32gui.GetWindowText(handle))

    titles = []
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
    return titles

titles = enum_window_titles()
```

Comment: This code will also execute under Python 2.x. It should also be noted that `GetWindowText` will frequently return an empty string indicating there's nothing in that window's title bar.

Comment: Thanks this helped to prove I was using the right Window names.  I have gotten it to work, but I still have a few kinks in other parts of the script I am working on.